# JPA and the Decorator Pattern

Tags: java, jpa, google-cloud-datastore, decorator

I am trying to create an application which will be partially dependent on the Census Department TIGER/Lines data Shapefiles, which have a record layout defined here:

http://www.census.gov/geo/www/tiger/tgrshp2010/TGRSHP10AA.pdf

My idea is to use the Decorator pattern to have a base Feature class with the fields common to all the data types, then extend it via the decorator pattern for the individual feature types (States, Counties, Congressional Districts, etc). However, I plan to use Google App Engine for hosting, so I have to do this via either JDO or JPA. I would much prefer JPA.

Can I map a decorated object? My idea is that the base feature class would be annotated with @Entity, then the extensions would contain the mapped fields specific to the decorated object. Since the GAE datastore is NOT an RDBMS, I'm thinking I can get away with it.

Comment: Link seems to be broken for me ATM, but I'll try to give some advice.  How you store data on Google's Datastore is highly dependent on how you plan to model it in your app, and how you plan to query the data.  The simpler you can make your data model, the easier it should be.  I found it kind of annoying to set up the correct entity relationships using JPA over Datastore last time I tried.  You also need to keep in mind how JPA will tell the Datastore to store the data.  Will entries be in the same Entity group?  These decisions will impact reads, write/transactions, and write frequency.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you use the Decorator pattern, it means that you use the composition. So what you can do is just mark the class you want to decorate as [Embeddable](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/persistence/Embeddable.html) and in your decorator, mark your decorated class as [Embedded](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/persistence/Embedded.html).

If you prefer to use the inheritance, your base class is not an entity since is just something you want to inherit and not store itself is the DB. To create a base classe which will be inherited from other real entities, there is an annotation for that : [@MappedSuperclass](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/persistence/MappedSuperclass.html)

According the [GAE docs](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/jpa/overview-dn2#Unsupported_Features_of_JPA), both are supported.

Hope it helps!